# Converting SLD to CSS style in GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, style, sld, css, geoserver-css-module

I am trying to convert SLD to CSS styles in latest geoserver version 2.8.1.

I have added css plugins(from geoserver-2.8.1-css-plugin.zip) but it is not working properly.

Is there any other plugin for converting from SLD to CSS style?

What is the solutions for this?

Comment: The CSS plugin in Geoserver works just fine.  However, it is not intended to convert SLD to CSS.  It converts CSS to SLD.  Geoserver natively uses SLD and not CSS.  The CSS plugin allows you to enter CSS (which is much easier to read and write than XML).  The plugin then converts that to SLD for internal use.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: @iant : going to migrate my project to css style

Answer (score 3):

The CSS plugin does a CSS to SLD conversion, the opposite is not always possible as long as CSS cascading is enabled.

On the current developer series (GeoServer 2.9.x) we have a directive to disable cascading, e.g., `@mode "Simple";` at the top of the file, that would allow one to write a SLD -> CSS translator... but it's not there yet. Contributions welcomed :-)